# Python check if one value is greater than the next one in array/vector

Tags: python, numpy, vector

Is there a way to check if one value of a vector is greater/smaller than the next one? Without using loops?

This is the vector:
1  2  4  3  6  9

And this would be the answer i need:
true true false true true

Comment: This smells like an assignment question... but yet, you can easily do it with zip, with two inputs offset my one.

Comment: `numpy` can also do it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the `diff` function in `numpy`. That will give you the difference between each value and its right neighbor. You can then check if that value is smaller or larger than 0.